# Set Visual Studio to create mdf file that SQL Server 2005 supports

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I added service–based database (`.mdf` file ) to my project.

The issue is that in the deployment server we have only SQL Server 2005 BUT SQL Server 2005 doesn’t support the `.mdf` file that Visual Studio 2010 created.

I can’t  change the SQL Server in the deployment server so my question is there any why to tell Visual Studio to create an `.mdf` file that SQL Server 2005 supports?

If so - what will be the impact to my code

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 by default installs SQL Server 2008 Express. If that doesn't work for you - uninstall it, and install SQL Server 2005 (Developer or Express) instead. The **best** solution would be to create the database **on the server** directly - instead of messing around with `.mdf` files.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always export the SQL script of your database out of any server version and execute the script on another (including lower) version of the server.

Since the script can contain both metadata and actual data, this option should make your database compatible with SQL 2005 even if you use a newer version on the development machine.